# Beacon detector using microcontroller and BLE

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, detector, bluetooth-low-energy, smart

I am looking for BLE device which can detect ibeacon or beacon module/tag.
I am interested to use microcontroller with BLE module instead of smartphone for beacon detector.

Can any one suggest where to start?
Does any BLE module with central role support beacon detection?
Can any one suggest BLE device name for beacon detection?

It would be really helpful, if you can provide hint for same.

Comment: Thanks Torsten, actually I don't want to develop/ modify BLE relates firmware but want access through AT command. Like give the AT command for scanning beacon and it(BLE device with central role) will return list of beacon with beacon frame. I found one forum for Redbear BLE MINI can scan beacon with HCI firmware. So I hope any BLE device can do this as you said. let me know if you have great idea than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use every device that implements scanning. With a nrf51422 you could directly access the radio hardware for example.